# How to find out parameter name for maven commands?

Tags: java, maven

I just imported a maven project (someone else's work) in eclipse where m2e plugin is installed. I was asked to create/run maven configuration based on readme.txt file.

I entered following command to Goals field after creating new Maven run configuration as the instruction said. Running the command was successful.

```
compile test -Dtest=HelloWorldTest -Dfoo=bar
```

My question is why I have to provide -Dtest as a parameter that points to a Java class (HelloWorldTest) that would be executed. Where it is specified? I could not find it neither from the class nor pom.xml file.

Comment: Most likely [`test`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test) parameter of Surefire Plugin...

Comment: I see. I noticed foot prints of surefire plugin from console when I ran mvn commands. I need to look up what it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have noticed you have run two phases of build cycle i.e. compile and test. Actually you just need to run 'test' phase which is after phase 'validate' and 'compile'.

For more details about maven build cycle you can go to
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

In the phase 'test', maven tries to run all of tests those classes who name ends with 'Test' by default. When the command line argument -Dtest is specified, maven would just run the test class specified in your case it is 'HelloWorldTest'. BTW the principle of 'convention over configuration' is used by default when using Maven.

Comment: if you can let me see your pom.xml, I can find out more about your question

Comment: Yes, you are right. I could have just run "test". Also you answered another question I had in my mind "..those classes who name ends with "Test" by default". Indeed, it is "HelloWorldTest' not "HelloWorld". I will correct it. Thank you for your kind offer but I am not allowed to share pom file in public. Have a blessed day!